# MySQL - return only 1 record for each certain id

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a newbie with sql.

I have this table with these records:

table `mark`

```
----------------------------------------
student_id | subject_id | comp_id | mark
----------------------------------------
 1         |  1         |   28    |  5.5
 1         |  1         |   29    |  7.5
 1         |  1         |   30    |  9.0
 1         |  2         |   36    |  9.6
 1         |  2         |   37    |  6.0
 1         |  3         |   42    |  4.0
```

I've tried this query `SELECT subject_id FROM mark WHERE student_id =1`

The results

```
subject_id
----------
1
1
1
2
2
3
```

How can i select the data with these result? I'm expecting something like this:

```
subject_id
----------
1
2
3
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  `distinct`

```
SELECT distinct subject_id 
FROM mark 
WHERE student_id = 1
```

or group the data

```
SELECT subject_id 
FROM mark 
WHERE student_id = 1
group by subject_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT subject_id FROM mark WHERE student_id =1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[DISTINCT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html)** clause to you can achieve it

```
SELECT DISTINCT subject_id FROM mark WHERE student_id =1;
```

Then you will get output as

```
subject_id
----------
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT subject_id FROM mark WHERE student_id =1 GROUP BY student_id;
```